# Getting install referrer when installing from FB requests

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

We are using the Facebook SDK for Unity (v6.2) for our game.
Our game is available on both Android, iOS and now Canvas.

We're sending different types of requests in the game to the player's FB friends. The behaviour (on mobile) is that if the game is not installed, the receiving user will be redirected to the store and then he could launch the game to receive the request.

During this flow, we lose all the information of the install referrer (we'd like to see whether a player installed our game as a result of a FB request).

Is there anything that we can do to support this scenario at the moment?

For users with the game installed, we get all the data using the GetDeepLink() method that passes all the parameters that launched the game. We need something similar for the install scenario.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution for this?