# FB.Mobile.AppInvite and triggering deferred app link

Tags: facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

### What I want to do:

Suppose that on FB-enabled game, A invites B. I want to use deferred deep link (on new installation) to trackback B's installation and launch, then give "invite reward" to A. That is, I must find a way to pass context from A's invite and stays until B's installation, which deferred deep link 'should' do the work.

### Problem:

App link URL specified when calling [FB.Mobile.AppInvite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Mobile.AppInvite) on A's side will not reach B on **first** app launch, neither as deep link or deferred deep link. [FB.Mobile.FetchDeferredAppLinkData](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Mobile.FetchDeferredAppLinkData) does state that

> Deferred deep linking is also useful to pass context on a new
>   installation when using FB.Mobile.AppInvite.

But "Test deep link" tool from [App Ads Helper tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/) did work and I got deferred deep link as intended.

These are steps I done

- A only has the app while B is not. A invites B.
- B goes to his FB notification, presses install on invite. At this point, I tried both install from real play store and switch outside then manually install APK by package manager.
- B launches an app, no deep link or deferred deep link provided. (Instead, if Test deep link were used to create invite, deferred deep link will show up here)

### Question:

- How to make app link reach B on first installation/launch? Or is there another trick or work around?
- If you are Facebook's developer team, maybe can you confirm that if this AppInvite really goes into deferred deep link or not? Or deferred deep link only designed for ads tracking?

### Note:

- This was tested on android.
- I have already setup deeplink option on FB app settings, and it passes check lists on [App Ads Helper tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper/).
- I have already delete the app on B side every time I tested.
- I'm on Unity Facebook SDK 7.6.0.
- I know that there are 3rd party service such as branch.io that might help, haven't tried those yet. I want to see if bare integration with FB SDK will work out of the box or not.

### Might similar to:

- [Getting install referrer when installing from FB requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677893/getting-install-referrer-when-installing-from-fb-requests)
- [How to use facebook deferred deep linking feature for new installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352690/how-to-use-facebook-deferred-deep-linking-feature-for-new-installs-and-to-test-t)

Comment: Update: There is a bug fired on developer.facebook that match this description. Now (July/7/2016) it is being assigned to Facebook team, but no outcome yet. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/586410544861095/

Comment: Bug reports says it is fixed on Unity plugin 7.7.0. Will test my scenario on it...

Comment: Looks like still not working in my case, might give up use invitable_friends workaround instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creator of this [Facebook Developer bug report here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/586410544861095/) confirmed that it was fixed in his case. So this issue was somewhat from plugin bug itself.

Still not fixed in my case, maybe due to different android activity configuration / presence of another plugins. But I will conclude this as answer to the question then.